# Integrate Google Maps API for specific module

Tags: angular, google-maps, angular-google-maps, angular-module

In my Angular project I am using lazy loading modules. For one specific component I want to use google maps API. I found three options how to integrate it. What is the best practise for performance? I see problems in all options. Is possible to load external js for specific module?

1. Add js file to index.html - loaded in all modules
2. Use npm library `@agm/core` - large library
3. Load dynamically this external js in this component in `ngOnInit` method - slow loading component

Thanks for response.

Comment: try to use angular google map, https://angular-maps.com/

Comment: @Haris angular-maps.com is my 2 point. And I don't like that this library is so large.